# What is the Proper way to Draw an Annulus (Wide Circle) using Bresenham's Algorithm?

Tags: geometry

Using only a box function, what is the proper way to draw an annulus (wide circle) using Bresenham's algorithm? I assume that consecutive parallel lines could be drawn, but that using an angled line instead of a point would be more feasible, but also involve trigonometry.

I am using Python, but examples in any language appreciated.

Comment: What is 'box function'? What is 'angled line'?

Comment: A box function produces a rectangle. An angled line consists of two points and is defined by y = kx. I could use a flat rectangle as a line.

Comment: But if you want you use lines directed along the radius - they are not lines, but triangles.

Comment: The width of the circle is defined by two points, not three. I am not sure what you mean...

Comment: Imagine inner radius 10, outer radius 20. Outer circumference contains twice as much points.If you draw lines from inner to outer, there will be empty places near outer circle.

Comment: I think that is actually closer to a solution, to draw two circles and store the coordinates pixelwise for each circle in separate lists, in order to create lines between the circles. However, there will be less pixels available to draw lines to in the outer circle, so the solution has to be to use triangles. OK! Gotcha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot fill all ring points with radial lines, because for `R2=2*R1` outer circumference contains twice as much points in it's raster representations, and there will be empty places near outer circle.

Graphics engines (DirectX, OpenGL and so on) often use triangle fans to fill the circles, ellipses, rings.

[image]